# RESTful URI design and implementation with derived classes using spring/ java

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Let's assume that we have fruit as a base-class and apple and banana as derived sub-classes.
I was wondering, which URI conventions and implementation would make sense the most. This one is straight forward:

```
GET /fruits - returns list of all fruits
GET /bananas - returns list of all bananas
GET /apples - returns list of all apples
GET /bananas/new - returns form for creating a new banana
```

Now, as Spring already handles the creation of the new object and setting all it's parameters, the method for saving the object comes down to:

```
fruit.persist(); // same for bananas and apples
```

So, how would you design the urls:

```
POST /fruits - creates a new fruit // as generic URI ... OR
POST /bananas - creates a new banana // same for apples
```

The problem, with the generic approach seems to be, that the method then will save the banana/apple as a fruit instead of a banana/apple:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private String saveFruit(@Valid Fruit fruit, Long basketId) {
    Basket basket = Basket.findBasket(basketId);
    fruit.setBasket(basket);
    fruit.persist();
}
```

I couldn't figure out, how to tell spring with subclass should be created although I am setting the right one, within the create-form (e.g. when calling GET /bananas/new):

```
uiModel.addAttribute("fruit", new Banana());
```

So currently I created two public methods for saving apples and bananas

```
POST /bananas - create a banana
POST /apples - create an apple
```

Implemented like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveBanana(@Valid Banana fruit) {
    String basketId = this.saveFruit(fruit);
    return "redirect:/basket/edit/" + basketId;
}
```

Somehow that does not satisfy my need to keep things DRY and simple.
Also because when editing a fruit I want to call something like

```
GET /fruits/123/edit - return the edit form of a fruit
```

The logic, which form-fields should be presented then is handled by the view.

One could also think of calling the sub-class controller, e.g. /bananas/123/edit, which decouples the code a little bit more and doesn't require changing files when adding a new fruit. What do you think, would be the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's *very* important that you don't let your framework dictate your **resource** design. HTTP doesn't know anything about base classes or subclasses, just resources. Forgetting the Spring framework, what are you trying to gain from an HTTP/ReSt perspective with your resource design?

If the only reason you are leaning towards `/fruits/{id}` is to save you repetition on the backend, then your design is being driven from internal concerns, not external ones.

If your `banana` resource has a different representation when formatted as JSON than an `apple` resource (e.g. new layout, different attributes, etc), then, IMHO, it likely deserves to be handled with its own resource.

Once you make that decision, then look at how you can accomplish that as cleanly as possible using Spring.

Comment: Pete, thanks for your advice. I just started to implement it that way. Whenever I have parts with the same logic I now use static methods of the base-class-controller (to keep it DRY).